# textField resignFirstResponder disappears UITableView header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have a `UITextField` inside a `UIView` which is used as the tableHeaderView of a `UITableView`.

When I call `resignFirstResponder` for the `textField` in order  to dismiss the keyboard, the whole tableHeaderView vanishes. Same happens when I try to reload the data of the tableview while the keyboard is up.

Any ideas why?

EDIT: Sample code

```
UITableViewCell *header = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mapViewCell"];
UITextField *searchField = [header viewWithTag:6];
searchField.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

and in a delegate method for textfield:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [searchField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Keyboard is dismissed but the whole `tableHeaderView` goes away (turns into white)

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by wrapping the `UITableViewCell` used as `tableHeaderView` inside a `UIView`:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[header frame]];
[view addSubview:header];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3,

```
let view : UIView = UIView.init(frame: (header?.frame)!)
view.addSubview(h)
tableView.tableHeaderView = view
```